# MVC 3 Form validation

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an app that is using standard out of the box form validation so when a user clicks the submit buttons and there are required fields not filled in, the validation message pops up next to the empty field.  This is great, however, because our form is quite long we also like to display the same error messages at the top of the page in a bulleted list or something.  Is there a quick way to do that?  I can't seem to find where the validation is getting triggered in the jquery code to add new code to it.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Rhonda

Comment: Actually, I figured it out and as usual, it was much easier than I anticipated.  Now I just need to figure out how to change the style of the defaul validation messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this that was quite simple.  I just put a div at the top of the page and put all the @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email) for every field in that div.  This way they show up in both places.

Rhonda